# Why Spring Roo is showing only a single addon?

Tags: spring, spring-roo

Running `addon search --refresh` returns only a single result:

```
roo> addon search --refresh
Successfully downloaded Roo add-on Data
1 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.2 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
01 - Y 0.1.0.BUILD Hindi language support for Spring Roo Web MVC JSP
       Scaffolding; #mvc,#localization,locale:hi
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using spring-roo version 1.2.2

```
roo> version
    ____  ____  ____  
   / __ \/ __ \/ __ \ 
  / /_/ / / / / / / / 
 / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /  
/_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.2.2.RELEASE [rev 7d75659]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a handful of problems with the addon repository in recent months - see [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-3184), for example. The (somewhat annoying) workaround is that if you can locate the URL for an addon you're interested in, you can still load it via the 'osgi obr url add' and 'osgi obr deploy' commands.  You can see an example [here](http://lalyos.github.io/blog/2012/09/24/spring-roobot-workaround/).